# How to get data from the store to filter by field. Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

For the contragent field, I need to set filtering. I can not understand how I correctly set the value in the parameter "store:".

```
    {
        text: 'Контрагент',
        dataIndex: 'contragent',
        filter: {
            type: 'list',
            store: //how to get the "name" of the record from the ContrAgents for filtering
        },
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
            if (value > 0) {
                if (rec = me.myContrAgents.findRecord('id', value)) {
                    return rec.get('name');
                }
            }
            return '';
        }
  }
```

I give an example in [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mr1) Location code app/view/ListView.js

Comment: Why dont you write filterFn function to filter store ?

Comment: @Tejas Location code app/view/ListView.js

Comment: @Tejas Local filtering will be enough